# How can I better import python modules with two scripts?

Tags: python, import, module

Let's say I have two scripts: **functions.py** and **algorithm.py**. In the former I write functions that are imported in the latter, which is the script that is run in the terminal.

So my script in algorithms.py looks like this:

```
import functions
x = functions.a_function()
```

If for instance I use numpy in `a_function()` but I don't use it elsewhere in algorithm.py, should I import numpy in functions.py or in algorithm.py (or both)?

With my lack of expierence in python I would like to know how people generally work out this particular problem.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always import a module where you use it.

If functions in functions.py use numpy, import it there; if the ones in algorithms.py use it, import it there. And if both do, import it in both places.

Comment: Would you define using numpy in algorithms.py if you use a function in algorithms.py imported from functions.py that uses numpy but not using numpy whatsoever elsewhere in the script?

Comment: No. Only import the things needed for the functions defined *in that module*.

Answer (score 0):

Try it by yourself.

If you use numpy in functions.py, you *need* to import it in functions.py (it is not about good or bad practice, if you don't, it won't even work) and it is *useless* to import it in algorithm.py.